# Why does my validation summary not render?

Tags: asp.net, validation, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, modelstate

I have this viewmodel:

```
public class PersonBindingModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

and a relevant portion of the `Create` view scaffolded for it by standard .NET Core and EF Core packages:

```
<form asp-action="Create">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>PersonBindingModel</h4>
        <hr />
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="LastName" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="LastName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    ...
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Yet when I omit the required `LastName`, I only get a validation message under that input, and the validation summary is not rendered at all. In all other forms in my project, the summary is rendered as well as the message under the `LastName` input. This is the rendered form:

```
<form action="/persons/Create" method="post">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>PersonBindingModel</h4>
        <hr>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="LastName">LastName</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input class="form-control input-validation-error" type="text" data-val="true" data-val-required="The LastName field is required." id="LastName" name="LastName" value="">
                <span class="text-danger field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="LastName" data-valmsg-replace="true">The LastName field is required.</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        ...
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    ...
</form>
```

I have omitted the client side validation, i.e. the `_ValidationScriptsPartial`, as I am testing the model binding validation controller side, together with an irrelevant custom validation I have added. The form renders just the same with or without the custom validation.

In the rendered HTML, you can clearly see the missing `LastName` has generated a `ModelState` error, and I have always been under the impression that in a form like this, as long as `ModelState` contains model errors, i.e. one's with input names as keys, the validation summary should render. Why isn't it?

Comment: Have you tried with `asp-validation-summary="All"`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke All the `All` option does is include messages you add with empty property name keys. I actually want to know why it is not showing my errors with valid keys, so I'm actually only interested in `ModelOnly`. But I'll give it a try anyway, thanks.

Comment: `asp-validation-summary="All"` equates to `@Html.ValidationSummary(false)` and `asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly"` equates to `@Html.ValidationSummary(true)`

Comment: Yes, @StephenMuecke, but the `true` and `false` represent "only display model errors" or "don;t *only* display model errors". I've been using the previous version for many years now, Besides, all my other summaries render whatever option I use.

Answer (score 4):

In this particular case i think it is the way you add errors to the "ModelState"

```
ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, x.Description)
```

Note that the **Key** is a **Empty string** , This is how the "ModelOnly" knows that it is not a Property Error.

If you have anything other than a Empty string it will count as a Property Error, and will only show in the mode "**ALL**"

Comment: I have both kinds of errors, with keys, and with `""` keys (not quite `String.Empty` but it normally worked before). In this case, it doesn't render anything for any combination of model and non-model errors.